# error when exporting predictions of 4 machine learning models

Tags: scikit-learn, nlp, classification, svm, prediction

I am training and testing my date on a kfold equal to 10 with 4  different models. I would like for each models to export the prédictions and the corrected classes for each split.

this is my code and the result :

```
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X, labels):
    print('TRAIN:', train_index,
        'TEST:', test_index) 

    X_train, X_val = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_val = labels[train_index], labels[test_index]


    model1 = LinearSVC()
    model2 = MultinomialNB()
    model3 = LogisticRegression()
    model4 = RandomForestClassifier()

    model1.fit(X_train, y_train)
    model2.fit(X_train, y_train)
    model3.fit(X_train, y_train)
    model4.fit(X_train, y_train)

    result1 = model1.predict(X_val)
    result2 = model2.predict(X_val)
    result3 = model3.predict(X_val)
    result4 = model4.predict(X_val)

    df = pd.DataFrame(data = {"id": X_val, "Prediction": y_val}) 
    df.to_excel('result.xlsx')
```

so far I have this below but it only prints the first lines (1-198) but i do not understand the export , could you help me

I have approximately 2000 sentences.

[image]

Comment: As is, you just overwrite `df` in each loop iteration (and in fact it prints the *last* iteration, not the first one); you need to initialize your `df` before the loop, and then append the results in each iteration.

Comment: ok, i will try!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set K in KFold == 10, the `.split()` method splits your dataset into 10 portions. For each iteration, `test_index` will be indices of the i-th portion while `train_index` will be the rest of the 9 portions.

In your original code, the `df` shows the test set (`X_val`, `Y_val`) (instead of the predictions) for each iteration.

I am not sure that you intend to do but if you would like to see the prediction for each model, the following code will do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    "id": [],
    "ground_true": [],
    "original_sentence": [],
    "pred_model1": [],
    "pred_model2": [],
    "pred_model3": [],
    "pred_model4": []})

for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X, labels):
    print('TRAIN:', train_index,'TEST:', test_index)

    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = labels[train_index], labels[test_index]

    model1 = LinearSVC()
    model2 = MultinomialNB()
    model3 = LogisticRegression()
    model4 = RandomForestClassifier()

    model1.fit(X_train, y_train)
    model2.fit(X_train, y_train)
    model3.fit(X_train, y_train)
    model4.fit(X_train, y_train)

    result1 = model1.predict(X_val)
    result2 = model2.predict(X_val)
    result3 = model3.predict(X_val)
    result4 = model4.predict(X_val)

    temp_df = pd.DataFrame(data={
        "id": X_val,
        "ground_true": y_val,
        "original_sentence": verbatim_train_remove_stop_words[test_index],
        "pred_model1": result1,
        "pred_model2": result2,
        "pred_model3": result3,
        "pred_model4": result4})
    df = pd.concat([df, temp_df])
```

Comment: hello it prints the result but only for the last test_set, I wanted to see for each test. and do you know how i can display the original sentences.

Comment: @kely789456123 I edited the code a bit using `concat` in each iteration will allow you to do so. As for displaying the original sentences, what method did you use to transform your sentences into the input features?

Comment: I use this line : ngram_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(binary=True, ngram_range=(1, 2))
ngram_vectorizer.fit(verbatim_train_remove_stop_words)
X = ngram_vectorizer.transform(verbatim_train_remove_stop_words)
total_verbatim = X.shape[0]

Comment: thank you but is it possible to merge all the 4 df in one unique data frame so that for each model, I will prédictions next to next ,  so as to have id; groundtrue, prediction_model1, prediction_model2, prediction_model3, prediction_model4

Comment: @kely789456123, I edited the code. See if it does what you'd like to achieve.